# Creating tweet with Twitterizer raises WebException 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitterizer

I am using Twitterizer, and am trying to get my ASP.Net app to upload reported traffic incidents to the official Twitter account.

I have looked at similar questions at SO, and the I tried all the recommendations (specify call-back url, check for careless errors and ensure the app has Read-Write permissions), but I still cannot solve the problem. I have some screenshots of the settings and code below. The callback URL does not exist, but is made up. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have problem with your internet connection? Can you directly access Twitter with http connection. I had the same problem because my company has a filter for twitter, facebook etc.

Comment: I can access Twitter directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this problem, this time I tried regenerating my API keys, and now it is working. Perhaps my previous keys were duds.

Answer (score 0):

Another item to look for is the computer time.  Look at the server time in the Twitter response and compare it to the computer you're using. Also, here's a troubleshooting guide from the Twitter site:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/204

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void UploadTweet(string token, string tokensecreat, byte[] img, string Title)
        {
            Twitterizer.OAuthTokens tokens = new Twitterizer.OAuthTokens();
            tokens.AccessToken = token;
            tokens.AccessTokenSecret = tokensecreat;
            tokens.ConsumerKey = TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
            tokens.ConsumerSecret = TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET;
            byte[] photo = img;

            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.UpdateWithMedia(tokens, Title, photo, new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });
            if (response.Result == RequestResult.Success)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```